# Resizing in Firefox sometimes removes part of the buttons

Tags: bug, design, user-interface, tag-watching, firefox

When I resize the page (typically on 80% in my case, because I find the text too large to read properly) some layout does not scale well. Incidentally, when I scale it even smaller, the buttons in the image are aligned properly again. Not sure this is a Firefox bug or an SO design bug.

[image: Layout slightly messed up]

Comment: @ShadowWizard, yes, indeed, that appears to be a duplicate.